# LINQ: Select <contition> OR <condition>

Tags: linq, select

Pseudo code:

SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE ('date' < today) OR ('visible' = false)

How do you do **OR** in Linq?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just use the language specific OR condition.  In C#:

```
var results = from row in table
              where row.date < today || row.visible == false
              select row;
```

If you prefer the method syntax:

```
var results = table.Where(row => row.date < today || row.visible == false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Reed nailed the C# one, here is the VB.Net equivalent

```
Dim results = _
  From row In table _
  Where row.Date < today OrElse row.Visible = False
```

Comment: Found it. My fault for rushing!